# TypeScript : TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: typescript

```html
       <div >
            <input type="file"  id="uploadImage"/>
            <button
                @click="Upload"
                style="width: 80px;height: 30px;"
            >
                upload
            </button>
          </div>
```

```js
  //upload()
    const upload = () => {
      const file= (document.getElementById('uploadImage') as HTMLInputElement).files[0];

    }
```

I want to get the value of < input type=file/ >, but there is the following error. How to write it will solve it?
TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

Comment: Typescript is telling you that your object is possibly null. Handle that case.

Comment: @异菌素 I'm sorry, I didn't have an accurate description just now, but now I've revised it.

Comment: What JS framework are you using?

Answer (score 6):

TypeScript is saying you must handle the case where `document.getElementById('uploadImage')` could return `null` and where `.files` could return null.

The first is not possible in your case because you are in a handler for `#uploadImage` so you can just add a dummy null check or even a [`non-null assertion`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator), that is, `input!.files[0]`.

```
const input = document.getElementById('uploadImage') as HTMLInputElement; 
// file may be null if use canceled out of the dialog
const file = input!.files?[0]
```

Another option would be to get the element from the event, but `.files` could still be null.

```
 const upload = (e: ) => {
      const file= (e.target as HTMLInputElement).files?.[0];
 }
```

Lastly, you should be checking for the `change` event, not the `click` since the user hasn't selected anything when they click.

You can see a [working example with plain TS here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-etqubd?file=index.ts) I don't know what framework you're using but it's not really relevant to your question.

```
// Non-null assertion because we know input exists.
const input: HTMLInputElement = document.querySelector("input")!;

input.addEventListener("change", function test(e: Event) {
  const file = input.files?.[0];
  // .files may be null, handle it properly
  console.log(file ? "File selected: " + file.name : "No file selected")
})
```